# Problem using free() in a loop creating a linked list from a file

Tags: c, linked-list, free

So I have a file called file.txt and i want to create a linked list from the information it contains, where each line of the file is a new node. So far I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct sAirport{
     char name;
     int number;
     struct sAirport *next;
}tAirport;

tAirport *createNode(tAirport *newNode, char str[1000]);
void createLinkedList(tAirport **head, tAiport *newNode);

int main()
{
     FILE *fa = fopen("test.txt", r);
     char str[1000] = {0};
     tAirport *head = NULL;
     tAirport *newNode = NULL;

     while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), fa) != NULL)
     {
          newNode = createNode(newNode, str);
          createLinkedList(&head, newNode);
          free(newNode);
          newNode = NULL;
     }
     return 0;
}

tAirport *createNode(tAirport *newNode, char str[1000])
{
     char *aux = NULL;
     newNode = malloc(sizeof(tAirport));

     if(newNode == NULL)
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

     aux = strtok(str, " ");
     strcpy(&newNode->name, aux);

     aux = strtok(NULL, " ");
     sscanf(aux, "%d", &newNode->number);

     newNode->next = NULL;

     return newNode;
}

void createLinkedList(tAirport **head, tAirport newNode)
{
     tAirport *temp = NULL;

     if(*head == NULL)
     {
          *head = newNode;
          return;
     }

     temp = *head;
     while(temp->next != NULL)
          temp = temp->next;
     temp->next = newNode;
}
```

I'm getting weird results and Valgrind says I have lost bytes but I don't know what to do.

Edited so that it can  run.

For example the file I'm testing with is:

John 33

Mary 42

Peter 12

What should I do?

Comment: I'm surprised this code even compiles. Turn on compiler warnings and fix the warnings first. Then look at your buffers, make sure you're not overflowing them. Finally, trace the lifetimes of the objects you allocate and make sure you don't free something you're still using.

Comment: I forgot the part where I open the file, but other than that what warnings are there?

Comment: Well for one thing, you pass a `tAirport*` to the `createLinkedList` function, even though it wants a `tAirport` (no `*`). Turn on warnings to find out what the other warnings are.

Comment: You´re talking about newNode?

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and find out.

Comment: I edited the code

Comment: Don't pass `newnode` as a parameter to `createNode()`, simply declare `newnode` in `createNode()` and return a pointer and assign it back in the caller. Have a look at [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB) for the list operations. Then look at the benefits of a *tail* pointer [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A)

Comment: [Still doesn't compile](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/AKuSSj), even [after I fix the typos in `tAiport` and `r`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T6futb). You also have a buffer overflow in `createNode`, and the way you're using `strtok` may not produce what you expect. Use a debugger and step through the code. The program is short enough that this is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from all those warning you will get from compiling this. I just want to tell you that you are misunderstanding how `malloc()`,`free()`, and pointer work.

First of all, pointer is just an `unsigned long`, a natural number just like any other number. The difference is that the pointer store the address of the real memory ( in this case is `newNode`).

In your program, you `malloc()` to get your memory, asisgn the memory address to `newNode`, then you tell your list to hold `newNode`, finally you free it. So you just free the memory you wish to keep, your list now only hold a bunch of address to freed memory.
Solution for this is, get rid of `free()` while populating your list, and free them later

Answer (score 0):

The `sAirport` structure is define the name to be one character. However, from the code, looks like the `createNode` will allow long name (up to 999 characters). When the `createNode` create the new entry, the strcpy will overwrite data beyond the allocated space, and will likely cause segmentation fault, or "funny" data.

Consider extending name to the proper size, or using dynamic allocation (malloc) for name.